# Do I need to change SOA on OVH to use AWS? If so, how?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, nameserver, amazon-route53, ovh

I bought a domain name on OVH, it's dnapc.ovh.

But, I want to store the DNS configuration on AWS. (I find this simpler to manage, and it's clearer this way what belongs to the AWS config and what belongs to the OVH config)

What I've done so far, is replacing the default OVH NS records by those provided by AWS for the Route53 dnapc.ovh Hosted Zone.

But, when I add DNS records for subdomain (CNAME), I still need to add them on OVH, I wish to do that on AWS. *(and, **understand why** it doesn't work by simply changing the NS)*

Note: Not sure if it changes anything, but I took the "Anycast" OVH option for that domain. *(which is probably useless, considering my plan is to change the NS and basically use AWS to configure the DNS)*

Here is the txt version of my OVH DNS config:

```
$TTL 3600
@   IN SOA dns200.anycast.me. tech.ovh.net. (2022101700 86400 3600 3600000 60)
                          IN NS     ns-879.awsdns-45.net.
                          IN NS     ns-1746.awsdns-26.co.uk.
                          IN NS     ns-1448.awsdns-53.org.
                          IN NS     ns-482.awsdns-60.com.
                          IN A      213.186.33.5
```

Do I need to change anything in the SOA record? I see it still mentions dns200.anycast.me and running a `whois` shows:
Name Server: dns200.anycast.me
Name Server: ns200.anycast.me

So, I guess I need to do something different, and SOA might be the way. But I don't want to blindly change things. Could you help me understand what's the missing piece here?

Here are the DNS records provided by AWS:
[image]

Here is what the "DNS Servers" looks like, on OVH:
[image]

Comment: It is not enough to change the content of the zone. You need to update the domain, through its registrar, to use at registry the new set of nameservers.

Comment: Adding to the first response. You need to change OVH to point to the Route53 name servers. You do that FROM the OVH side. See https://docs.ovh.com/us/en/domains/web_hosting_general_information_about_dns_servers/#modifying-dns-servers

Comment: Thanks, so I need to re-add the 4 AWS NS records there, right? So, in my case it would be `ns-879.awsdns-45.net.` linked to the one IP address AWS provided for me? I added a screenshot about what it looks like on OVH.